# How do I create a nested tree with terms & nodes with Views 3?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I need to create something similar like this:

Colors (Vocabulary)

- Red (term)

  - Dark (term)

    - Node 1
    - Node 2
  - Light (term)

    - Node 3
    - Node 4
- Blue (term)

  - Node 5
  - Node 6
- Green (term)

  - Node 7
  - Node 8

(Bullet points are indents.)
Is there a way to do this with Drupal 7 and views 3? If not, is there another way to do this?

Comment: To clarify - as perhaps I misunderstood your question - you want to display a structure like this on one page?

Comment: Yes on only 1 page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to refino, I found a nice solution using the following modules:

- [Views Tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree)
- [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view)

Below you find the explanation:

1. First create a new Taxonomy (let's call it "Folder")
2. Then, create a new content type (let's call it "Element") with a term reference field to the "Folder" taxonomy
3. Create a new "Content" View (let's call it "Element View")
4. Choose Field Display
5. Add a Contextual Filter to your term reference field
6. Create a new "Taxonomy" View (let's call it "Folder Tree")
7. Add 2 fields (term name and term id). The second field can be excluded from display
8. In Relation: add a "parent term"
9. Add a third field (term id) and assign it to your parent relation. This field can be excluded from display
10. Choose Format "Tree (Adjacency model)" and select in the parameters : Ordered list + Main field (your first tid), Parent field (your tid assigned to the parent relation). You now should have a nice tree with all your terms nested
11. Add a 4th field "Global:View" (this comes with Views Field View) and choose your "Element view", display Master add [tid] in the Arguments textfield

Hope this help

Cheers

Edit by **iStryker**:   This is what I got.  The only thing I changed was make *Element View* a table view, and removed the default (row & strip) classes.

[image: Image of the final product by iStryker]

Comment: A great help from this comment. Just a minor note: you might want to rename the fields (Administrative titles) because in the VT settings dropdowns both the "Term ID" fields will be indistinguishable.

Comment: This answer got me 90% there.  
I needed to remove default classes on each field;
Remove table classes on 'Element View' view;   
Theme a little

Comment: I've added a step to reduce duplicates in the Content view. Also, "Arguments" field in Global:View is now labeled "Contextual filters" and the token to use is "[!tid]".

Comment: Is it possible to do this but with Organic Groups instead of Taxonomy?

Answer (score 14):

I created three views in Drupal 7.8 and Views 3 + Views Field, nesting one view into another using Include View, and I got such a result (attached). [image]

Step-by-step how to do it:

1. Create vocabulary "Colors" and fill it in with tags.
2. Create a new view of taxonomy nodes Colors - I call it "Nodes of
   Colors"

2.1 Format Table , Settings: Grouping field: Taxonomy term: Name

2.2 Advanced Contextual filters: Taxonomy term: Parent term

2.3 Advanced Relationships: Taxonomy term: Content using Color

2.4 Set Fields: Taxonomy term: Term ID, Taxonomy term: Name,
    (field_color) Content: Title

2.5 Filter criteria: Taxonomy term: Vocabulary (= Colors)

2.6 If you want you can also set "Exclude from display" for Term ID,
    Taxonomy term: Name

2.7 Set Path:/nodes-of-colors/%

2.8 Set no results behavior: Global: View area (we will come back to
    this later)
2.9 save

3.Create a new view of taxonomy nodes Colors - I call it "Nodes of Colors 2"

3.1 Format Table , Settings: Grouping field: none

3.2 Advanced Contextual filters: Taxonomy term: Term ID

3.3 Advanced Relationships: Taxonomy term: Content using Color

3.4 Set Fields: Taxonomy term: Term ID, Taxonomy term: Name, (field_color) Content: Title

3.5 Filter criteria: Taxonomy term: Vocabulary (= Colors)

3.6 If you want you can also set "Exclude from display" for Term ID, Taxonomy term: Name

3.7 Set Path:/nodes-of-colors-2/%

3.8 Set no results behavior: Global: none

3.9 Save

Go back and edit "Nodes of Colors" again

4.1 go to Set no results behavior: Global: View area

4.2 Set View to insert: View: nodes_of_colors2 Display: page

4.3 set Inherit contextual filters

4.4 save

5 Go back to Views again (Type Term)

5.1 Create a new view of taxonomy nodes Colors - I call it "Colors Tree"

5.1 Format Table , Settings: Grouping field: none

5.2 Advanced Contextual filters: none

5.3 Advanced Relationships: Taxonomy term: Parent term

5.4 Set Fields: Taxonomy term: Term ID, Taxonomy term: Term ID , Taxonomy term: Name, View: Include View (Include View)

5.5 Filter criteria (1): Taxonomy term: Vocabulary (= Colors)

5.6 Filter criteria (2): (Parent) Taxonomy term: Term

5.7 If you want you can also set "Exclude from display" for Term ID and a label of Include View

5.8 Set Path:/colors-tree

5.9 Set no results behavior: none

5.10  save

...and this should be it, finally.

Comment: can you clarify "5.4 set fields ... view: include view" a bit more. I don't see an option for that anywhere. Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I didn't write I used Views 7.x-3.0-rc1 + Views Field 7.x-1.0-rc1

Comment: ok, thank you. I followed some instructions on their issue queue as well http://drupal.org/node/1171604

Comment: Wow, this answer has gotten a massive upvote in the pass 7 days.  Has anyone tested this though, or you/they just upvoting because @Refineo gave the most detailed answer?

Comment: I tried this walkthrough again, and didn't work.  I hated you all who upvoted this question is the last week without testing

Comment: @iStryker, I tested this on my own Drupal system before posting the answer. Maybe I can help you setting this up?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried the D6 or D7 version of this myself but I thought I would mention it in case it's what you're looking for: [Views Tree Module - D7 progress](http://drupal.org/node/1044362)

*Edit*:  There is now a D7 version, checkout the module homepage [Views Tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the vid from the URL then use the following code.

```
$vid = $_GET['vid'];
$tid = 0;
$level = 0;
print taxonomy_tree($vid, $tid, $level);
function taxonomy_tree($vid, $tid = 0, $level) {
  $children = taxonomy_get_children($tid, $vid);
  $output = '';
  if ($children) {
    $output .= '<ul>'; 
    foreach ($children as $child) {
      $level++;
      $output .= '<li class="taxonomy-tree-lvl' . $level . ' ">'; 
print $level;
      $output .= l($child->name, 'taxonomy/term/'. $child->tid) . '(' . taxonomy_term_count_nodes($child->tid) . ')'; 
      $output .= taxonomy_tree($vid, $child->tid, $level);
      $output .= '</li>';

      $level--; 
    }
    $output .= '</ul>'; 
  }

  return $output;

}
```

Or use the following code.

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load(2);//Here pass the vid
print $vocabulary->name;
$vid1 = $_GET['vid'];
if(!$vid1) {
$vid1 = 2;
print 'empty';
}
$vid = 2;
$parent = 0;
print get_child_terms($parent, $vid1);
 function get_child_terms($parent, $vid) {
      $sql = "SELECT td.tid, td.vid, td.name"
         . "  FROM {term_data} td"
         . "  JOIN {term_hierarchy} th on th.tid = td.tid"
         . " WHERE th.parent = %d"
         . "   AND td.vid = %d"
         . " ORDER BY td.weight, td.name";
    $terms = db_query($sql, $parent, $vid);
    $output = "";
    while ($aterm = db_fetch_object($terms)) {
        $output .= "<li>";
        $output .= l("$aterm->name", "taxonomy/term/$aterm->tid/all") . " ("
                .  taxonomy_term_count_nodes($aterm->tid) . ")</li>\n"
                .  get_child_terms($aterm->tid, $vid);
    }
    return ($output != "") ? "<ul style='list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  padding: 0px;'>\n". $output ."</ul>\n" : "";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is:

1. Set up your hierarchival vocabulary,
2. Add it to any selected content type,
3. Create a view listing nodes from that content type, with **contextual filter**:

   - either "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" - if you want to list only nodes assigned to specific term,
   - or "Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)" - if you want to list nodes assigned to a specific term as well as to its child terms.

     In this case, in filter configuration you need to set the depth - how many levels below (or above) you want this filter to work.

Then, assuming your view's URL is http://mysite.com/myview and 'Red' tid = 1, if you go to http://mysite.com/myview/1 it will list you all nodes assigned to either one of terms 'red', 'dark' and/or 'light'.

Comment: I'm not looking for an answer for a specific term.   I'm looking for a view for the entire vocabulary

Comment: And that's exactly what I've described.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Transforms your taxonomy vocabularies into menus with ease!
>
> Features:
>
> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with Views
> - Integrate with Pathauto: use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules

Comment: Welcome to Drupal SE! taxonomy_menu is a cool project and it can do this nicely. OP wants to do it in Views though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to accomplish the same but haven't found much available in D7. 
[Taxonomy Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_blocks) module does it in a block - not views.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found yet another way to solve this problem, and I think it's simpler than the rest of these solutions. It does not involve any extra modules and you only need one view.

Assuming you have created a *two level* hierarchical vocabulary (Colors) and a content type with a term reference to that vocab, do the following:

1. Create a new view and filter by "Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name (= Colors)"
2. Add relationships: (1) `Taxonomy term: Content using Color` and (2) `Taxonomy term: Parent term`
3. Add the fields to the View: (1) `Title` (choose `field_color` in "Relationship" **and require this relationship**), (2) `Taxonomy term name` (do not use relationship and exclude from display) (3) `Taxonomy term name` (yes, again, this time choose `Parent` for relationship and exclude from display).
4. Now group it by clicking on Settings of Format: (1) grouping 1: `(Parent) Taxonomy term: Name`, (2) `Taxonomy term: Name`

Done. If you have more than two levels just add another Relationship of Parent using Parent as the relationship's relationship.

EDIT: if you don't require the relationship you'll end up with dupes. Parents will be listed twice if they have child terms that are referenced by nodes. So this limits the answer a bit in that top-level terms without nodes that reference it won't display. Also, because sorting is probably important, having any content referencing a top level term would potentially cause problems for you depending on display needs.

Comment: There is no filter "Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name (= Colors)" until add relationship. I suspect first step is to be second. Also I could not understand how to add field Title when choosing field_color in "Relationship".